# Not all pre-reqs install correctly for Hyperledger Composer

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger-composer

I've been following the Hyperledger Composer tutorial.   I managed to install Ubuntu 16.04 on Hyper-V on my Windows 10 Enterprise.  I then started on the following pre-req installation instructions:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/installing-prereqs.html

I ran the prereqs-ubuntu.sh script.  It ran fine with no errors.  I examined the logs and saw that it had successfully installed npm 5.6.0, node 8.9.4, docker 17.12.x, docker composer 1.13.x, and Python 2.7.12.

However, when I run run $ sudo npm --version
it tells me that the npm command is not found

Same with $ sudo node --version
Not found...?!

Why would that be when the log clearly shows that npm and node where successfuly installed?!

Comment: Did you log out and log back in again as requested by the script ? nvm updates your login session scripts to ensure node/npm are added to the path. Also don't use sudo the point of the script is to set up node/npm so you don't use sudo. Using sudo will introduce other issues and it isn't required.

Comment: I must have not closed the shell yesterday.  Today I closed it, and logged off and back on and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what I did and managed through:

--> install nodejs and npm:

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel=8
```

so you get the latest node8.

--> then to solve "sudo" problem with node specify the npm prefix:

```
npm config set prefix ~/.node_modules
```

add the following to .bash_profile

```
export PATH=$HOME/.node_modules/bin:$PATH
```

Now the packages will install into your user directory and no permissions will be harmend.

--> install nvm (to get exactly node 8.9 version on the next step):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

*or*

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

Verify:

```
node -v nvm
```

which should output 'nvm' if the installation was successful.

--> get and set node 8.9 version:

```
nvm install v8.9.0 
nvm use 8.9.0
```

--> reset PATHs:

```
echo export PATH="$HOME/npm/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
npm config set prefix ~/npm
echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/$USER/npm/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

--> at this stage the docker previous setup shall be destroyed:

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images dev-* -q)
```

--> Installing the rest of prereqs:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update

# install git    
sudo apt-get install -y git

# Ensure that CA certificates are installed
sudo apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates

# Add Docker repository key to APT keychain
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

# Update package lists
sudo apt-get update

# Verifies APT is pulling from the correct Repository
sudo apt-cache policy docker-ce

# Install Docker
echo "# Installing Docker"
sudo apt-get -y install docker-ce

# Add user account to the docker group
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)

# Install docker compose
echo "# Installing Docker-Compose"
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.13.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" \
    -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

# Install unzip, required to install hyperledger fabric.
sudo apt-get -y install unzip
```

--> now you can install Fabric dev. env. (assuming the rest of prereq components stand available):

```
npm install -g composer-cli
```

*etc.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to log out and close the shell. And then restart with the new session, as the shell stores your session.

Also, after installation, the use of `sudo` is not recommended as mentioned on IBM hyperledger website.