# ./stopFabric.sh fabric not stopping

Tags: docker, dockerfile, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

./stopFabric.sh
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'stopFabric.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv11
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)
Stopping peer0.org1.example.com ... error
Stopping orderer.example.com ... error
Stopping couchdb ... error
Stopping ca.org1.example.com ... error

ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot stop container 89b76dbf64bc360c5ba0fe4233b4e20e3e6466c721b5ef1e0952503de67d7030: Cannot kill container 89b76dbf64bc360c5ba0fe4233b4e20e3e6466c721b5ef1e0952503de67d7030: rpc error: code = 7 desc = permission denied

ERROR: for ca.org1.example.com  Cannot stop container 5054fb8ad55c1b2fdecd849885106748404e1ccbbc7add7faf759be8e857e53a: Cannot kill container 5054fb8ad55c1b2fdecd849885106748404e1ccbbc7add7faf759be8e857e53a: rpc error: code = 7 desc = permission denied

Comment: what's your docker version ?

Answer (score 0):

this is a Docker issue rather than a Composer issue firstly..docker version pre-reqs described [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs)

So I'm wondering if you're getting a similar setup issue as described in the ANSWERS here -> [Error on last step of Hyperledger Fabric installation of local runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48332652/error-on-last-step-of-hyperledger-fabric-installation-of-local-runtime).

Another answer from the docker forums is posted here -> [Docker Containers can not be stopped or removed - permission denied Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223280/docker-containers-can-not-be-stopped-or-removed-permission-denied-error)

Answer (score 0):

Try manually deleting `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` and then `docker network prune`